# React Native with Router v4 Match tag giving component undefined

Tags: react-native, react-router-v4

I was trying out react router native with react router v4 based on this [link](https://medium.com/@jschloer/react-router-v4-with-react-native-5f2005ab2a72#.55qfcl94p)

The `Match` tag is giving me an error

`React.createElement: type is invalid — expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it’s defined in. Check the render method of`

The components are available, and I even tried with explicitly creating the component.

Full code
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
      import {
        AppRegistry,
        StyleSheet,
        Text,
        View,
        TouchableHighlight,
      } from 'react-native';
      import { Match, Miss, MemoryRouter as Router } from 'react-router';

```
  const componentFactory = (routeName) => () => (
    <View>
      <Text style={styles.route}>{routeName}</Text>
    </View>
  )

  const NavLink = ({to, children}, context) => {
    const pressHandler = () => context.router.transitionTo(to);
    return (
      <TouchableHighlight onPress={pressHandler}>
        {children}
      </TouchableHighlight>
    )
  }
  NavLink.contextTypes = {router: React.PropTypes.object}

  export default class RR4Native extends Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <Router>
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <View style={styles.routeContainer}>
              <Match exactly pattern="/" component={componentFactory('Home')}/>
              <Match pattern="/about" component={componentFactory('About')}/>
              <Match pattern="/topics" component={componentFactory('Topics')}/>
              <Miss component={componentFactory('Nope, nothing here')}/>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.container}>
              <NavLink to="/">
                <Text style={styles.routeLink}>
                  Home
                </Text>
              </NavLink>
              <NavLink to="/about">
                <Text style={styles.routeLink}>
                  About
                </Text>
              </NavLink>
              <NavLink to="/topics">
                <Text style={styles.routeLink}>
                  Topics
                </Text>
              </NavLink>
              <NavLink to="/broken">
                <Text style={styles.routeLink}>
                  Broken
                </Text>
              </NavLink>
            </View>
          </View>
        </Router>
      );
    }
  }

  const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      flex: 1,
      justifyContent: 'center',
      alignItems: 'center',
      backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
    },
    route: {
      color: '#701010',
      fontSize: 40
    },
    routeLink: {
      color: '#0000FF'
    },
    routeContainer: {
      flex: 1,
      justifyContent: 'center'
    }

  });

  AppRegistry.registerComponent('RR4Native', () => RR4Native);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the final release of `react-router` there is no `Match` nor `Miss`. You just need to use `Route`. In your case, you need to do the following:

```js
<View style={styles.routeContainer}>
    <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={componentFactory('Home')}/>
        <Route path="/about" component={componentFactory('About')}/>
        <Route path="/topics" component={componentFactory('Topics')}/>
        <Route component={componentFactory('Nope, nothing here')}/>
    </Switch>
</View>
```

See [NoMatchExample in React Router docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/no-match) for details.